# sqlite query to return ordered case-sensitive AND case-insensitive hits

Tags: sql, sqlite, collation

Lets say a I have database with a table of words, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE Words (
  Id integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  Word text NOT NULL
);
CREATE INDEX Word_Index ON Words (Word ASC);

sqlite> SELECT * FROM Words;
Id|Word
1|apple
2|Apple
3|Jack
4|jack
```

To keep things simple, lets just say that I only care about ascii characters, as far as case sensitivity goes.

What I would like to do is perform a search for Word and first return the row that returns the exact case sensitive match, followed by all rows that match, ignoring case, without duplicates.
So for example, SELECT * FROM Words WHERE … ‘**Apple**’
would return:

```
2|Apple
1|apple
```

and likewise, SELECT * FROM Words WHERE … ‘**apple**’
would return:

```
1|apple
2|Apple
```

I’m primarily concerned with the case sensitive matches, but would like them to be followed by case-insensitive matches, as a fallback. I’m expecting that usually I’ll get hits for the case-sensitive matches, which is why I have a case-sensitive index. I realize that the case-insensitive fallback won’t be able to use the index, but I’m opting to not have a second (COLLATE NOCASE) index in order to save space in my database, since it would probably be used infrequently anyway. Usually I'm only going to be stepping once, grabbing the first hit.

What’s the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

To make both case-sensitive and case-insensitive searches efficient, you need two indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX Word_Index ON Words (Word);
CREATE INDEX Word_Index_nocase ON Words (Word COLLATE NOCASE);
```

It is not possible to use efficient index lookups when you're doing tricks with ORDER BY; you have to do separate lookups for case-sensitive and case-insensitive matches, and filter out the duplicates from the second result:

```
SELECT *
FROM Words
WHERE Word = 'Apple'

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM Words
WHERE Word COLLATE NOCASE = 'Apple'
  AND Word <> 'Apple';
```

(To handle non-ASCII characters, you'd need to install a custom collation).

Comment: This works nicely. If my understanding of the query plan bytecode (too large to paste here) is correct, if I omit the second COLLATE NOCASE index then I'm only penalized for not having it when I step beyond the preceding case sensitive hits. Do you concur?

Comment: Yes; SQLite computes result rows only on demand (as far as possible).

Comment: Of course, you could generate all possible letter combinations of case-insensitive `aPpLe`, and search for all of them explicitly …

Comment: Coming back to this, wouldn't it make more sense to use just `UNION` rather than `UNION ALL` so that the `AND Word <> 'Apple'` could be skipped? Am I missing something?

Comment: `UNION` puts all results into a temporary index (B-tree) to be able to detect duplicates. Just checking a value for not being "Apple" is faster because it doesn't need to be compared with other rows.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Words
WHERE LOWER(col) = LOWER('Apple')
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN col = 'Apple' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),
         col;
```

SQLite is case sensitive by default.

You can try this, but I don't know if it will use the index:

```
SELECT *
FROM Words
WHERE col = 'apple' COLLATE NO CASE
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN col = 'Apple' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),
         col;
```

Comment: That definitely seems to work, but the query plan indicates that it's not using the index:
--EQP-- 0,0,0,SCAN TABLE Words
--EQP-- 0,0,0,USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
I'd like to be able to use the index in cases where I step only once to grab the first (case sensitive) hit, when one exists.